# What is this yellow checkmark in Xcode project navigator view?

Tags: xcode

```
Anyone know what this means?
```

I don't recall seeing it before, and hovering over it doesn't show anything. Should I be fixing something?

[image: xcode screenshot]

Comment: Right click, then click "Show in Finder," then you should be able to see the file extension

Comment: It's the entitlements file

Comment: So there's your answer. That's the icon for an entitlements file. You know what an icon is, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this yellow checkmark is an entitlement file.

Entitlement file: These are Key-value pairs that grant executable permission to use a service or technology.

Whenever we add a capability to our project then this file is automatically generated.

For example: When I added push notification capability in my project,then an entitlement file is created with the same name of the project.

The below screenshot shows that I have a project named Stackoverflow when I added push notification capability then the Stackoverflow entitlement file is generated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was concerned by the color wondering why it isn't green. I guess yellow is normal.

Comment: Yes, it's by default yellow in color.